# Access Azure Blob Storage data from Azure SQL Database/SQL Server as a blob (for read and write), not for a table import

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

All other questions and answers I have found on this topic reference accessing a CSV/Excel file (e.g. via OPENROWSET or BULK INSERT) rather than as a blob.

Is it possible, from within a Stored Procedure, to access Azure Blob Storage (for a particular, known file URL), and output the actual file's data as a varbinary(max) column from a stored procedure? Similarly, in reverse, is it possible to accept a varbinary(max) as a stored procedure parameter and subsequently write that file to Blob Storage from within Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction would be: *why would you*?

If there's a reason to combine data from SQL with data from a file, your logic should probably do that. Use tools and services for what they're there for, and what they're good at. Reading (information from) files from within (Azure) SQL is not one of them.

With that being said: it does not seem possible without `OPENROWSET` or `BULK INSERT`.

Closest that is out there is an option to [SQL Server backup to URL for Microsoft Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url) but even that's only available for SQL Server and Managed Instance. The fact even that is not possible with Azure SQL probably tells us something like this is not going to possible.